# Why is the 2nd figure in a subfigure on the bottom?

Tags: tables, beamer, figure-placement

Here is my code:

[image]

Here is the output:

[image]

Why is the table on the bottom?

Comment: Please don't show your code as image, we can't copy&paste from it to reproduce your problem.

Comment: As you aren't using numbered captions, I would use beamer columns instead of figures. This way you avoid the problem that the first line of the table aligns with the baseline of the image.

Comment: Great. The columns worked much better. Thank you!

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I added an answer saying why it aligns as it does but you could steal a tick by saying what the OP should do instead (rather than close)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Looking forward to see a nice green tick attached to your answer!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ... and please feel to mention columns if you'd like

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz is that a picture mode feature?

Comment: Note that subfigure (which is basically a minipage) suuports an optional argument for [t/c/b], although in many cases [t] and [b] are the same.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It should be a picture mode feature: to easily position your picture mode plane beside your picture mode duck!

Answer (score 2):

By default a tabular has its reference point at the left edge of its vertical center line, so the baseline of your figure runs through the baseline of the caption on the left and the cemtre of the tabular on the right.

If you used a caption on the right, or even `\vspace*{0pt}` or used `\begin{tabular}[b]`  then the reference point would be below the tabular or (for `[b]`) on its last line and so the alignment would be different.